# Android check for digits in array of char

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have the following command which I am trying to convert. How to convert this command to `Java` and run on `Android`?

```
textBox2.Text.ToCharArray().Any(c => Char.IsDigit(c))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
TextView textBox2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textBox2);
Pattern ps = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z ]+$");
            Matcher ms = ps.matcher(textBox2.getText().toString());
            boolean bs = ms.matches();
            if (bs == false) {
                //fail
                             } 
             else{
                //success  
                  }
```

Alternative: you can just do it from the XML file of the TextView like this

```
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
```

Please test and edit for your needs tho. But the idea is to use a *regex* for your needs.